# Redirect to jqGrid edit form directly without displaying the grid

Tags: jqgrid

Often I need to edit a single record in a database without the need to display the grid at all. I can hide the grid using CSS or jQuery. What I couldn't figure out is to directly go to the edit form from another webpage while hiding the grid.

I know it's kind of defeating the purpose of having a grid, but it's one of those cases where only a single record should be view and modified by the users similar to the Access single record mode. Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: Could you write any comments on the answers on your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can just hide so named "gbox" created over the grid and then call [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method with the options which you like to have. As the result you will have the form which close to what you want. I am sure that you have to make some other small problems, but the first look can be like you want. Moreover you can scroll over the rows during editing.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditingHiddenGrid.htm) demonstrate what I mean. It displays the following form

[image]

The demo uses the following code

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    ...
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        $(this).jqGrid("editGridRow", data.rows[0].id, {
            modal: true,
            overlay: 0, // create no overlay
            onClose: function () {
                return false; // don't allow to close the form
            }
        });
    }
}).closest(".ui-jqgrid").hide();
```

Comment: Got it! What I missed is to use loadComplete event. Didnt' know it was so easy.

Comment: Hi I am trying to use my own custom edit form. Is it possible if yes mean please help me how to do. else guide me alternatively for this

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: Yes, `navButtonAdd` allows you to add custom button which can create your custom edit form. Alternatively you can use `editfunc`, `addfunc` and `delfunc` parameters of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters).

Comment: as usual your answer saved my day... Thanks a lot @Oleg. I used this for add record option. And now trying to implement for search record.

Comment: I'm having little issue in this. I am using this for add record. If I click on the save button data posted successfully. But I want to close the add form. I tried `closeAfterAdd:true`. It is closing the form. But I can't click anywhere in current window after close. @Oleg

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons I like to use my own custom edit forms, instead of the one built into jqGrid. Then you can just open it like you would from the jqGrid handler (with appropriate parameters of course), no grid required.

Comment: Hi I am also trying the same will you please share me how to call the own custom edit form.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam - Add an edit button to your grid, and from the handler just open a jQuery UI Dialog (or your preferred dialog control).